# Merge de dois objetos com o mesmo ID

Tags: node.js

Preciso concatenar dois objetos que tenham a mesma `id`.

Exemplo:

```
a1: {id: 1, qtde: 2}
a2: {id:1, nome: 'teste'}
```

Resultado:

```
a3: {id: 1, nome: 'teste', qtde: 2}
```

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Se quiseres podes marcar uma das respostas como aceite.

Answer (score 3):

Tendo em conta que JavaScript referência objetos, tens dois caminhos:

- acrescentar propriedades ao objeto original
- criar um objeto com as propriedades dos outros (sem alterar os originais)

Para acrescentar, podes fazer uma função para combinar (fazer *merge*) esses objetos.

```
function mergeInto(source, target) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {
        target[key] = source[key];
    });
}
```

Nesta caso a função não precisa de `return` pois o objeto `target` é mudado por referência.

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/5pu4n3h9/

**Para manter os originais**, como indica a resposta do [@tayllan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118546/129), tens de criar um terceiro objeto e adicionar proriedades de ambos. Nesse caso poderia ser assim, e a função já teria de ter `return`:

```
function mergeObjects(sourceA, sourceB) {
    var obj = {};
    var keys = Object.keys(sourceA).concat(Object.keys(sourceB));
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        if (sourceA.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj[key] = sourceA[key];
        if (sourceB.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj[key] = sourceB[key];
    });
    return obj;
}
var c = mergeObjects(a, b); // Object {id: 1, nome: "teste", qtde: 2}
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/5pu4n3h9/2/

Comment: realmente, encapsular em uma função deixa mais claro. E utilizar o `.hasOwnProperty()` pra garantir que não vai pegar propriedade herdada pela cadeia de protótipos também é uma boa. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Se a única `key` que os objetos possuem em comum for `id` e você tiver certeza de que o valor vai ser sempre o mesmo, então basta iterar sobre as propriedades dos objetos e adicionar os valores ao terceiro objeto:

```js
var a1 = {
 id: 1,
 qtde: 2
};
var a2 = {
 id: 1,
 nome: 'teste'
};
var a3 = {}

Object.keys(a1).forEach(function(key) {
 a3[key] = a1[key];
});

Object.keys(a2).forEach(function(key) {
 a3[key] = a2[key];
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(a3));
```

Comment: Isso numa função ainda ficava melhor :) `+1`

Comment: obrigada pessoal, deu certo.